# In eclipse, how do I get the debugger to show all stack frames without clicking expand on each of the threads?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I have a server that has 100 running threads, and I would like to know if there is a easy way to expand all threads  to show their stack frames, in one click.

Comment: Im not sure this question is a fit for this site...

Comment: @Neal: A question about how to debug in a *development* environment not for stack overflow???

Comment: Even if that's possible, I somehow doubt that you should be doing this. If you have to analyze the stack traces of 100+ threads, getting the stacktrace in a useful format and analyzing that programmatically seems much simpler.

Comment: My application seems to have a dead lock. I just wanted to see where it is.

Comment: @Voo This is something that I a bit. For debugging threading bugs, it at least gives an easy list to scan for methods. Now if only there were a way to collapse `Object.wait()`, and `PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(SocketImpl)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the top level thread (or the application) and then `[Shift]+[Right Arrow]`. Depending on your level, you may need to do this twice.

Comment: Awesome, that works like a charm! But, why would you have to do it more than once; just curious.

Comment: I'm running in tomcat, and if I highlight the application, once expands the top level thread to it's children, and then again to show all the stacks. (Can you accept my answer now? ;p)

Comment: Works in Eclipse Luna. Then you can search with ctrl-f in all method names.

Comment: So simple, yet so helpful.